# Somatório query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Estou tendo um tipo de problema com esta Query, mas o que eu quero que aconteça é para todos os valores como: `Goals Scored`, `Assists Made`,`Key passes` etc, para fazer somatório para cada ID do Jogador tornando-os aparecer apenas uma vez.

```
SELECT s.[Statistics ID], s.[Player ID],  s.[Game ID],  s.[Season ID],  s.[Goals Scored], s.[Assists Made],  s.[Key Passes], s.[Successful Tackles],  s.[Successful Interceptions], s.[Goals Conceded], p.[Player Name], p.[Player ID]    
FROM Statistics$ s, Players$ p
WHERE s.[Player ID]=p.[Player ID]
```

Isto é o que aparece na visualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Miranda a sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Tente explicar melhor o que pretende.

Answer (score 1):

Para somar utiliza o SUM(campo) e para fazer com que o jogador seja exibido apenas uma vez utiliza DISTINCT campo ou pode agrupar usando GROUP BY campo:

```
SELECT
  DITINCT p.[Player ID],
  SUM(s.[Goals Scored]) AS gols_jogador,
  SUM(s.[Assists Made]) as assists,
  SUM(s.[Key Passes]) as passes
FROM Players$ p
INNER JOIN Statistics$ s ON s.[Player ID]=p.[Player ID]
```

Espero que de certo :)